# Clean test database, only of the data generated running the tests with RSPEC and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have an application in **rails 4.1** to which I am doing the test with RSPEC and Capybara, for her I have a test database with data that I use to perform the tests, I am running a test that generates some data that are stored in the bd, or what I need is that after running the tests these data are not stored in it.

I have used the gem database_cleaner (clean test database, only of the data generated running tests with RSPEC and Capybara), but this clears all the data of the test bd and I only want to erase the data that are generated by the tests.

I have this configuration, and the test is a javascrpit test:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.before(:suite) do
        if config.use_transactional_fixtures?
             raise(<<-MSG)
             Delete line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` from rails_helper.rb
             (or set it to false) to prevent uncommitted transactions being used in
             JavaScript-dependent specs.

             During testing, the app-under-test that the browser driver connects to
        uses a different database connection to the database connection used by
            the spec. The app's database connection would not be able to access
            uncommitted transaction data setup over the spec's database connection.
            MSG
        end
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

    config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
        driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

        if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
            DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
end
```

Comment: Finding it hard to understand why you don't want the database in a clean state for each test you run - what is the purpose of having data in your test database at all - could you clarify your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating records in the tables that contain the data you want saved in your tests, then there's no easy way (simple configuration change of database_cleaner, etc) to do what you want - maintain data existing at the beginning of the test. That's because that would be the transactional mode for database_cleaner which isn't compatible with Capybara and JS test in rails 4.1 (in Rails 5.1 transactional mode is compatible and database_cleaner is no longer needed for most configurations)

If you're not creating/deleting/updating records in the tables you want saved from your tests then you can tell database_cleaner to skip those tables.

Since it's not easy to do what you want you should ask yourself exactly why you're trying to do something most other people aren't and maybe adjust the way you're doing things.

If you still want to continue with what you're trying to do (and you aren't modifying any of the existing data in your tests (just adding new rows) then you'll need to create a before hook that stores the maximum id in each table, and then an after hook that removes records with larger ids, and not use database_cleaner

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very helpful

You tell me that it is not the right way to do what I want, could you tell me then what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Andres23Ramirez Normally feature testing is done by setting up just the records required for a specific test at the beginning of that test.  That way each test is fully isolated from the other tests. You may have a really good reason for not doing that, but without a lot more detail/examples about exactly why you want to pre-populate your test DB with a bunch of data before all the tests it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: This reset the bd of tests, what I need is that no data is saved in the bd so that the other test cases are not affected, but from the same execution

Comment: You can try using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)

Comment: And use the [:truncation](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#what-strategy-is-fastest) option

Comment: I do not need a command, if not the appropriate configuration form of rspec and Capybara to return the data after each test but without deleting all the bd

Comment: @ChetanDatta I think he's already using database_cleaner and the truncation option.